# Spring Batch :: ItemReader to fetch data from MySQL and Salesforce

Tags: mysql, salesforce, spring-batch

Requirement :: Synch data between MySQL(Customer) and Salesforce(Account)

For the above requirement I plan to use Spring Batch and use ItemReader1 to read data from MySQL table - CUSTOMER. Now based on ItemReader1 result use the "CustomerName" field and fetch the corresponding Salesforce ID value from Salesforce Account SObject. Is this the right approach ?

(MySQL -- CUSTOMER )  - CustomerId, CustomerName, CustomerProject, CustomerPhone
(Salesforce -- Account) - Id,CustomerName,AccountName,AccoutnPhone

Comment: Finally what you are going to achieve?

Comment: By reading the data using the above approach I have the SalesforceID and the corresponding Customer values that I need to update in Salesforce. I plan to write all these data to a CSV file using the ItemWriter. Once this is complete, an other Spring batch job will be looking for this CSV file and updates all these data in Salesforce Account object using Salesforce BulkAPI.

Comment: is it a single step job or multiple steps? Have you figured out about combining those two readers?

Comment: I completed the data sync between MySQL and Salesforce using Salesforce BulkAPI